# Android cursor getColumnIndexOrThrow gave me an error

Tags: android, cursor, managed

I am currently using managedQuery to query the images in the sdcard by using the mediastore but it couldn't get through the function getColumnIndexOrThrow and pop out a error dialog on the emulator.

image_cursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

```
    if (image_cursor == null)
    {
        TextView test = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        test.setText("null");
    }
    while ( image_cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (image_cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            TextView test = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            test.setText("entered");
        int index = image_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);

        //  TextView test = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        //  test.setText(image_cursor.getString(index));
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

```
index = image_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE);
```

[MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#CONTENT_TYPE) is not a column name, it's the MIME type of the directory of images.

To find the image columns, look at [MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html) and  [MediaStore.MediaColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html).